# C# System.NullReferenceException even though initilized

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm using C# and trying to insert a row into a SQL table.  I have the following code.

```
    string spaceObjectName, RA, DEC;
    spaceObjectName = txtSpaceObject.Text;
    RA = txtRA.Text;
    DEC = txtDec.Text;

    adsJarvis.InsertParameters["spaceObjectName"].DefaultValue = txtSpaceObject.Text;
    adsJarvis.InsertParameters["RA"].DefaultValue = RA;
    adsJarvis.InsertParameters["DEC"].DefaultValue = DEC;

    try
    {
        adsJarvis.Insert();
        txtSpaceObject.Text = "";
        txtRA.Text = "";
        txtDec.Text = "";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "A database error has occurred.  Message: " + ex.Message;
    }
```

My problem occurs with this line:

```
adsJarvis.InsertParameters["spaceObjectName"].DefaultValue = txtSpaceObject.Text;
```

For whatever reason, I'm getting this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can't for the life of me figure out why, since I've checked, and I know     spaceObjectName isn't null.
Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong? Any hints would be much appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are you instantiating adsJarvis and what type is it?

Comment: @attila In the .aspx file.
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="adsJarvis" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Code/adbJarvisStars.accdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [spaceObjectTable]" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable( spaceObjectName, RA, DEC) VALUES (spaceObjectName, RA, DEC"></asp:AccessDataSource>

Comment: From the line you claim is the problem, any of `adsJarvis`, `adsJarvis.InsertParameters["spaceObjectName"]`, or `txtSpaceObject` being null at run time will raise the exception, and at least one of them *is* null.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot You were right, 'adsJarvis.InsertParameters["spaceObjectName"]' is null, but I still don't know why.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd assume you never added an object with that key to the collection.

Comment: If you are going to reference your InsertParameters like that, then you need to create them on your aspx page, inside of your asp:AccessDataSource tag. There is an example here - http://www.databaseskill.com/3132661/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your snippet, `adsJarvis.InsertParameters["spaceObjectName"]` is of course null because the compiler is looking for paramater named `spaceObjectName`, that's why it throws a NullReferenceException. You need to reference that in your aspx page.

Try this:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="adsJarvis" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Code/adbJarvisStars.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [spaceObjectTable]" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable( spaceObjectName, RA, DEC) VALUES (?, ?, ?)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="spaceObjectName" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RA" Type="string" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DEC" Type="string" />
        </InsertParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

so in your code behind you can:

```
adsJarvis.InsertParameters["spaceObjectName"].DefaultValue = ...;
....
```